# how to route (navbar link) react website to another page specific element/component (like anchoring) with or without react-scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-scroll

### the website i am trying to author, has 2 pages

| page | route path | components | details |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| home | '/' | navbar,videgallery1,videogallery2,footer |  |
| concepts | '/concepts' | navbar,imggallery1,imggallery2,footer |  |

Each page main component (video or image gallery) is twice for reason. its same but with different json content etc. (kind of category)

| item | description |
| --- | --- |
| '/' | video gallery 1 (10 videos), video gallery 2(RealTime Section) (10 videos) |
| '/concepts' | image gallery 1(conceptart,50 images), image gallery 2 (Moodboards Section,40 images after concept art gallery) |

#### Main Question

- i am trying to add 'RealTime' link via react-scroll (in nav file). it works when i am on homepage ('/') route. But fails when i am on second page (/concepts). How to tell it to first go to '/' then try to scroll to element or component.?
- same is case with 4th link (moodboards), it works from concept page but not from home page.
- also please notice that 'Link' is from ReactScroll is disabled, as i was trying to test react-scroll.
- if this can be acheived without react-scroll, that would be even better.

#### [CODESANDBOX LINK](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-portfolio-website-minimalist-f1jivw?file=/src/App.js)

- here you can see, realtime link working on main page but not working when you are in concepts page.

**navbar.js**

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
// import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Link, DirectLink, Element, Events, animateScroll as scroll, scrollSpy, scroller } from 'react-scroll'

import MyLogo from '../img/logo_ff2_2021.png';
export default function Nav(){

  // navlinks can have a class of active, which can be styled, comparing to links
  // classname, style, children, to, exact
  return(
        <div className="navbar">
          <div className="logo">
            <img src="assets/logo_ff2_2021.png" style={{width:'100%'}} alt="logo" />
          </div>
           <ul className="nav-links">
              <NavLink style={({isActive}) => {return isActive ? {color: 'red'} : {}}} to="/">Home</NavLink>
              <Link  style={({isActive}) => {return isActive ? {color: 'red'} : {}}} to="RT" spy={true} smooth={true} duration={500}>RealTime</Link>
              <NavLink style={({isActive}) => {return isActive ? {color: 'red'} : {}}} to="/concepts">Concepts</NavLink>
              <Link  style={({isActive}) => {return isActive ? {color: 'red'} : {}}} to="Moodboards" spy={true} smooth={true} duration={500}>Moodboards</Link>
           </ul>
        </div>
  );

}
```

**home.js**

```
import headerVideo1 from '../assets/slide_rag.mp4';
import MyCarousel from '../components/Carousel';
import StickyFooter from '../components/Footer';
import VideoGallery from '../components/VideoGallery';
import VideoGallery2 from '../components/VideoGallery2';
import {  DirectLink, Element, Events, animateScroll as scroll, scrollSpy, scroller } from 'react-scroll'
import './Home.css';

export function Home() {

    // const videos = getVideos();
    return (
        <>
        <MyCarousel />
        <VideoGallery name="main" />
        <Element name="RT" className="element">
        <VideoGallery2 name="RT" />
        </Element>
        <StickyFooter />
        </>
    );
}
export default Home;
```

**app.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Nav from './components/Nav';
import { BrowserRouter , Route,Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from './pages/Home';
import Concepts from './pages/Concepts';
import NotFound from './pages/NotFound';

function App() {

  return (
    <>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
        <Nav />
      </div>
    <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home/>} />
          <Route path="/footer" component={<StickyFooter/>} />
          <Route path="/concepts" element={<Concepts/>} />
          <Route path="/about" element={<About/>} />
    </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: *Other than* the `NavLink` component the code you've provided doesn't appear to really be using `react-router`. The other links don't appear to routes you can navigate to. Could to create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code we could inspect live?

Comment: missing app.js also linked(via edit) codesandbox [link added](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-portfolio-website-minimalist-f1jivw?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: When linking from say, "concepts" to the "realtime" section, are you wanting it to change page, and *then* animate? Id caution against this, usually this would be seen as a UX issue and jarring. You probably want to go the page, but already scrolled to the right section. Does that sounds ok? Can help further when I learn what you prefer.

Comment: yes, 100%  right..>>(You probably want to go the page, but already scrolled to the right section. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest importing and using link components from [`react-router-hash-link`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-hash-link). You set the `id` attribute on a DOM element on the page you are linking to, and use this hash target in the link.

`Nav` Example:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { NavHashLink } from 'react-router-hash-link'; // <-- import link component
import MyLogo from "../img/logo_ff2_2021.png";

export default function Nav() {
  return (
    <div className="navbar">
      <div className="logo">
        <img
          src="assets/logo_ff2_2021.png"
          style={{ width: "100%" }}
          alt="logo"
        />
      </div>
      <ul className="nav-links">
        <NavHashLink // <-- render link component
          style={({ isActive }) => {
            return isActive ? { color: "red" } : {};
          }}
          to="/"
        >
          Home
        </NavHashLink>
        <NavHashLink
          style={({ isActive }) => {
            return isActive ? { color: "red" } : {};
          }}
          to="/#RT" // <-- pass route and hash to target
          smooth
        >
          RealTime
        </NavHashLink>
        <NavHashLink
          style={({ isActive }) => {
            return isActive ? { color: "red" } : {};
          }}
          to="/concepts"
        >
          Concepts
        </NavHashLink>
        <NavHashLink
          style={({ isActive }) => {
            return isActive ? { color: "red" } : {};
          }}
          to="/concepts#Moodboards" // <-- pass route and hash to target
          smooth
        >
          Moodboards
        </NavHashLink>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Home

```
export function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <VideoGallery name="main" />
      <div id="RT" className="element"> // <-- wrapper div with "RT" id to target
        <VideoGallery2 name="RT" />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit how-to-route-navbar-link-react-website-to-another-page-specific-element-compon]

Comment: umm, it surely solve the problem, but on main home page, RT link already showing 'red' active (by default) is it possible to fix as well.

Comment: @haseeb Yeah, I also just noticed that. Compatibility between `react-router-hash-link` and `react-router-dom@6` is a work-in-progress. You could either revert back to `react-router-dom@5` or do a bit of state management around selected hashes to do additional matching over just the link's `isActive` prop. Does this make sense?

Comment: unconsciously (yes, it make sense) consciously(not exactly) (new / learning react) will try n confirm and if failing will shout for more help, huge thanks again for guidance.

Comment: @haseeb No worries. Just ping me here in comment if you need help.

Comment: @haseeb Coincidentally I just answered a question about a very similar issue matching the "active" hash routes [here](/a/75124180/8690857).

Comment: second answer(related similar issue) solved all my problems, huge thanks again. have a good day