# How to scroll to a div on React if i'm on a different page of the app?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

i'm trying to create an app in React with different pages, in my homepage i have different sections and when i'm in a different page that is not the homepage i would like when i click on the links in the header to go in the homepage and scroll to that specific div but i don't get how to realize it?

this is how is structured my Homepage component:

```
function Homepage = () => (
<>
<Section1 />
<Section2 />
<Section3 />
...
)
```

this is how is structured my header

```
...
<div className={} onClick={toggleMenu}>
   <ul className={Style.header__linkscontainer}>

    <li className={Style.header__linkitem}>
     <Link className={Style.header__link} to="/#section1">About</Link>
    </li>

    <li className={Style.header__linkitem}>
     <Link className={Style.header__link} to="/#section2">About</Link>
    </li>

    <li className={Style.header__linkitem}>
     <Link className={Style.header__link} to="/#section3">About</Link>
    </li>
   </ul>
</div>
...
```

this is structured my app

```
function AppContent() {
    return (
        <>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
                <Route path="/privacy-policy" element={<PrivacyPolicy />} />
                ...
            </Routes>
```

in HTML without react i can do it easily if i write in the path "/#section1" but on react this it works if i'm in the homepage, but not if i'm in another page, can someone advice me the right way to solve it?

i've tried to use instead of link's tag the a's tag, i've tried to write the path in the route but nothing worked.

Comment: Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/75122075/8690857

Comment: Thank you a lot!!! That's what i was looking for